# How to change the Email that get notified when a new case is opened

Tags: civicase, evaluating-civicrm

I am new to Civi CRM, been reading the docs and can't for the life of me find where to set what email gets notified when we open up a new case.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have that feature by itself but check out the add-on for webform (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm).

Alternatively, the case will appear on the case manager's dashboard so if you set that role on the case to the appropriate person when creating a case you can achieve a similar thing.

Comment: If you have case set up with a timeline so an Activity is auto-created - will the assignee of that Case get the notification?

Comment: By itself no, neither for the case manager role nor an activity assignee. If an activity is created via the UI the activity assignee will get an email, subject to the "Notify Activity Assignee" checkbox at /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display, but that would be a separate step after case creation and I think by assignee we're actually talking about case manager so just mentioning to clarify.